# Analytical Geometry, Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

[image]

Hello! I have some problems with understanding these. Could someone explain what need i do ?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. The solution for problem 15 looks like that for 14

Comment: For problem 14 you could multiply the second equation by $3$ and subtract the first equation to eliminate $x$ and solve for $y$

Comment: you are asked to find the point of intersection, that is, the common point that those lines share, the way to do that is to solve the system of equations determined by the equations of the lines, those are simple systems of equations, you can solve them with substitution or elimination, once you obtain your solution x, you replace it in one of the equations and compute the coordinate y.